# Is there any way to say that "I does"

Tags: conjugations

Is there any way to say

> I **does**?

Is it permissible to treat the conscience **I** as a singular treatment in formal or informal language?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to say that. For example, if you're extremely uneducated and don't care about English grammar at all. There is a guy in America that goes by the name of Beetlejuice (you can look him up on YouTube). He tends to use that kind of grammar when he speaks: *I hates them.*, *Sometimes I does*.

Comment: Notice that the first-person pronoun "I" is capitalized. Your original post has been edited to fix that error.

Comment: So, it is not possible to say that to make my speech more assertive?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make those sounds.  But then you are not speaking standard English, nor are you speaking one of the regional or social dialects of English.

It is not commonly found in informal spoken English, and learners should not find any context in which they should say "I does".